can clinicJS be used on production or any live servers?
lately, I came across ClinicJS, I want to know if I can use it for mentoring my application on AWS ECS.
I went throw the API docs, it looks so interesting, and I tried it locally, but I wondering of the possibility of having it on my ECS server, if no, is there an alternative for it?
